# Get the upcoming month from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an Array with some month and year.for ex array {Jan 2015,feb 2015, june 2015, september 2015}. I want to get the index of the current month and am getting it. If there is no current month, then i want to get the upcoming recent month.In the above example i want to get the index of september 2015.

Help much appreciated.

Below is the code to get the index of the current month.

```
   if ([titleMonth isEqualToString:currentMonth])

    {

    indexNumber=[[self.dataByMonth valueForKey:@"title"]indexOfObject:currentMonth];

    }
```

Here am getting the current month from  NSDate.

Comment: do you want the `upcoming` month, as in the next month? or the recent month? as in the previous month?

Comment: next month from the array, check the example above, i want the index number for september, not the index number of july.

Comment: instead of an array of NSString can you use array of NSDateComponents instead?

Comment: how that works with NSDateComponents ?

Comment: ... or just use `NSDateFormatter`. For what reason have you ended up with an array of strings?

Answer (score 1):

#### Create NSDataComponents

First, you need to fill the array with NSDateComponents objects. Look at [this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components:fromDate:) in particular.

For example. To create NSDateComponents for current month.

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]components:(NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Then fill up your array with these components.

Loop through the array until the current month and year is equal or lesser than the looping month and year. If they are equal, you have your current month. If its lesser, the item in the array is the next month/year.

Would this work?
Here is a rough sample code

```
for(NSDateComponents *components in arrayOfMonths)
{
    if(currentMonth.date == components.date)
        NSLog(@"current month is on the list");
    else if(currentMonth.date < components.date)
    {
        NSLog(@"this is the next month on the list");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your first array is {Jan 2015,feb 2015, May 2015, september 2015}. Keep another array with all the months {Jan 2015,feb 2015,Mar 2015,..... Dec 2015}.
If current month is June and it is not there in 1st array. Take the next element in 2nd array and check with the 1st array. So, check July is there in 1st array and continue this process until you find match. So, you will get September 2015.

Don't know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, but how will you check after the current month ?

Comment: You have the list of all months in 2nd array right. if june is not in 1st array, take july from 2nd array and check with 1st array, next, take aug from 2nd array and check with first array. Continue this process taking next next elements from 2nd array.

Comment: Can you please add some sample code. It would be much helpful.

Comment: How will you get the next month from the 2nd array to check with first one ?

Comment: 'currentIndex = [array2 indexOfObject:currentMonth];  
while(currentIndex < [array2 count]) {  
    if( [array1 containsObject: currentMonth] ) {  
        upcomingRecentMonth = currentMonth;  
        break;  
    }  
    else {  
        currentIndex ++;  
        currentMonth = [array2 objectAtIndex: currentIndex];  
    }  
}'